# Which Angular TS code should I use to communicate with the backend server and why? One solution is XMLHttpRequest and the other HttpRequest, both work

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I tried both solutions and they both work great. The XMLHttpRequest seems simpler to me. Are there pros and cons, what are some examples? Thanks in advance

```
  onRunJS030823d() {
    alert("onRunJS030823d");
    this.http.get<CatFacts1[]>('http://localhost:5072/StkMarketV2').subscribe(result => {//StkMarketV1 is in proxy.conf.js
      this.Data21 = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
    alert("Passed");
    for (let dat33 of this.Data15) {
      alert(dat33.fact);
      alert(dat33.length);
    };
  }
```

XMLHttpRequest:

```
  onRunJS030823h() {
    alert("onRunJS030823h");
    var url2 = "http://localhost:5072/StkMarketV2";//this works with cors
    alert(url2);
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const params = new URLSearchParams();
      xhr.open("GET", url2, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
          alert("In Solution Data (onload): " + xhr.responseText);
        };
      }
      xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        alert("Error Msg: " + xhr.statusText);
      };
      xhr.send(null);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first example in your question is a "high level" abstraction provided by Angular for a HTTP call, when the second example is a javascript more "low level" approach.

The Angular abstraction it is using under the hood something more "low level" similar to the second example in your questions.

It is better to use the angular abstraction (so the HTTP module) because in this way you will let Angular to handle some stuff under the hood, and also you will can use in the future some simple solutions provided by Angular for some other stuff (like interceptor etc).

So, by using the HTTP module you will be able to focus more on your business requirements and less on some technical stuff about the HTTP calls, not also for API calls itself, but for a lot of other different things directly or indirectly related to the API calls.

Comment: When I created the backend API myself both calls worked. When I tried to call a public site like https://catfact.ninja/fact the first call didn't work. I had to use the XMLHttpRequest. I'm guessing the public site somehow blocked me?